# Using CursorLoader in android instead of startManagingCursor, database access

Tags: android, android-cursor

I'm new to android development and I've got a little stuck with the new API, I can't seem to find a tutorial to help.

I've got a database with a SQLOpenHelper and a Database adapter that I've seen used in many examples, such as [this](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html).  I want to hook up the data into a list, so have created a ListFragment.  The tutorials that I've seen use the startManagingCursor(c) method in Activity, however the documentation says that this is depreciated and to use CursorLoader.

To use the CursorLoader it looks like I need a uri, which implies I need a content provider.  I don't need a content provider for my app, so I'm not sure how to implement this or what is the correct/ recommended way.

A shove in the right direction would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I've read and understood, the Android team encourages the use of a `ContentProvider` that sits in front of your database. As you can see with `CursorLoader`, the Android API is also encouraging this usage pattern.

Letting aside discussions if this is the best approach for small apps, I think you should not fight the API and go with a ContentProvider. `CursorLoader` handles a lot of stuff for you and I find it works really well.

Comment: OOh thankyou, I didn't want to put in extra code for the sake of it, but if this is the preferred approach then I will do this! :)  Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. If you look at any Android apps done by people at Google, they all use content providers. Also, don't forget to use android:exported="false" in your AndroidManifest.xml for your provider. This way, the provider is visible only for your app.

Comment: @kaciula could you provide some links to the resources you read. I'm trying to understand all this and haven't found any official sources yet.

Comment: @tidbeck All the resources can be traced back from http://developer.android.com Follow the Android developers Google+ page, follow the google group for android developers etc. It does however take  time to be up to date to what happens in the Android ecosystem.

Answer (score 3):

Some points that I need to add here

- Use `CursorLoader` instead of `startManagingCursor`. It is easy to use and more safe
- Check [The Problem with "Managed Cursors"](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/07/loaders-and-loadermanager-background.html), explain that correctly
- Definitely the best approach is to use [content provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) in front of your database to get the uri
- It is very simple to implement Content provider with your db, check [Simple Content Provider for db operations](http://myandroidnote.blogspot.com/2011/11/at-last-i-concluded-it-is.html)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use ContentProvider, that's Google teams encounge to do. Remember the three layers  in database book:storage, logic,application. Contentprovider act as the logic.